# Como integrar las imagenes desde una url en la base de datos y usando laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

El siguiente código es una prueba para acceder a la base de datos de mi servidor y quisiera saber como implementar una imagen usando la url que esta en las tablas de mi base de datos, se que debo usar el metodo asset que me permite acceder a las imagenes que se encuentra en la carpeta asset pero no se como concatenarlo adecuadamente

```html
    <h1>Listado de Libros</h1>
@foreach($producto as $producto)
<h3>{{ $producto->titulo }}</h3>
<img src="{{asset(img/$producto->imagen)}}" alt="productoimagen" width="250">
@endforeach
```

Comment: Pues como cualquier otro string con el punto,`{{asset('img/' . $producto->imagen)}}`

Comment: ¿cuál es el error que aparece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/'.$producto->imagen) }}" alt="productoimagen" width="250">
```

**Edición**

Con el helper `asset()`, lo que hace laravel es construir la URL completa al path que le pasas como parámetro. Es decir, concatena tu nombre de dominio o servidor, delante del path que le pasas por parámetro.

Por ejemplo, que si tu llamas a `asset('img/logo.png')`, la función te va a devolver `http://tu_servidor.com/img/logo.png`.

Por lo tanto, en tu raíz de la aplicación, dentro de la carpeta `public/`, tienes que tener una carpeta de imágenes `img/` (según lo que le estás pasando a la función `asset()`), y dentro de ella, la imagen que te esté devolviendo `$producto->imagen`.

PD. Si algo no te queda claro, pregunta sin necesidad de hacer un downvote.

Comment: no me sirve por mas que lo intento hacer asi

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar una explicación a lo que hace este código? Asi quizá entiendas los demás que tengan el mismo problema, pasate por [answer], así nos traes una respuesta con mayor calidad.